# Pytesseract gap in output

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract to get text files out of PNGs. Actually everything got extracted properly except one important ratio. In following input the ocr ignores "2,30" in the second line. This is the case in hundred's of PNGs. Other ratios like the ones below are extracted all the time properly. That doesn't make sense for me. Input Running Code
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr4VJ.png)
[Running Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LQ7g.png)

I've tried various configuration like dpi, oem and psm in the image_to_string function. As well I made sure that the PNG quality is as high as possible.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)